# Convert satellite image terrain mesh colours to new solid colours

Tags: mesh, texturing

To attempt to explain - I followed CG Geek's tutorial for converting a satellite / aerial photo to a terrain mesh (https://youtu.be/Mj7Z1P2hUWk) - which worked fine, however I am curious if there is any way to convert the existing mesh colours (which are basically the colours from the photo) to different, more 'solid' colours (i.e. replacing each mesh grid colour with a similar colour within a certain threshold).

I am basically trying to make the terrain look defined. The only aerial photos available are fairly low resolution so when you zoom in it becomes obvious that it's a low-res photo stretched over the terrain.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Maybe of some use, our [community resources](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender/15358#15358) at least for better imagery. Consider adding some reference to your question, that may help other users answer.

Comment: Are we talking shader-whise? There is a threshold node, but it might be tedious to set up.